# TikZ: using name intersections to define a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, foreach

Two questions:

1. What is going wrong with these nodes that are defined from the intersections?
2. Can this be automated with `\foreach` syntax to find the other vectors for the 2nd point?  I couldn't figure that out.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%  Used for both ellipses and circles                                               
\tikzset{%                                                                          
  partial ellipse/.style args = {#1:#2:#3}{%                                        
    insert path = {+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
  }
}

%  unit vectors                                                                     
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (4, 0) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(x\)};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 4) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(y\)};
  \draw[blue, name path = arc] (O) [partial ellipse = -15:75:3];


  \foreach \i/\angle in {1/60, 2/30}{
    \path[name path global = line\i] (O) -- (\angle:3.5);
    \path[name intersections = {of = arc and line\i, by = P\i}];
    \path[name path global = circ\i] (P\i) circle[radius = 1bp];

    \filldraw[black] (P\i) circle[radius = .025cm];
  }

  \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = circ1 and arc}] (A1) at
  (intersection-1) {};
  \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = circ1 and arc}] (A2) at
  (intersection-2) {};
  \draw[name intersections = {of = circ1 and arc}, -latex] (P1) --
  ($(A2)!.75cm!(A1)$) node[pos = 1.125, font = \tiny] {\(\unit{u}\)} coordinate
  (B1);

  \draw[-latex] (P1) -- ($(P1)!.75cm!-270:(B1)$) node[pos = 1.125,
  font = \tiny] {\(\unit{n}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From the image, we see that first point is drawing correctly it just has associated errors with it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the error you get now just use the following code inside your \foreach loop (pgf-manual p. 496):

```
\path[name path global/.expanded = line\i] (O) -- (\angle:3.5);
\path[name intersections/.expanded = {of = arc and line\i, by = P\i}];
\path[name path global/.expanded = circ\i] (P\i) circle[radius = 1bp];
```

This will permit you to use path defined inside the `\foreach` loop outside the loop.

---

If just copy your last command inside the `\foreach` loop you get the following error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@intersect@path@names@parse was complete.
```

This is because the `of` key (\tikz@intersect@path@names@parse) expects spaces around `and` which is obviously stripped if you use `of = circ\i and arc`, so you will need to use `of = {circ\i} and arc`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%  Used for both ellipses and circles                                               
\tikzset{%                                                                          
  partial ellipse/.style args = {#1:#2:#3}{%                                        
    insert path = {+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
  }
}

%  unit vectors                                                                     
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (4, 0) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(x\)};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 4) node[pos = 1.1, font = \scriptsize] {\(y\)};
  \draw[blue, name path = arc] (O) [partial ellipse = -15:75:3];


  \foreach \i/\angle in {1/60, 2/30 }{
    \path[name path global= line\i] (O) -- (\angle:3.5);
    \path[name intersections = {of = arc and line\i, by = P\i}];
    \path[name path global = circ\i] (P\i) circle[radius = 1bp];
    \filldraw[black] (P\i) circle[radius = .025cm];
    \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = {circ\i} and arc}] (A1) at  (intersection-1) {};
    \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = {circ\i} and arc}] (A2) at  (intersection-2) {};
    \draw[name intersections/.expanded = {of = {circ\i} and arc}, -latex] (P\i) -- ($(A2)!.75cm!(A1)$) node[pos = 1.125, font = \tiny] {\(\unit{u}\)} coordinate (B1);
  \draw[-latex] (P\i) -- ($(P\i)!.75cm!-270:(B1)$) node[pos = 1.125, font = \tiny] {\(\unit{n}\)};
  }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]